# generate marshmallow-sqlalchemy ModelSchema like JSONAPI format

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restplus

I am using flask-Restplus for API, and in `GET` method I want to return JSON like JSONAPI format:

```
{"data":[
  {
     "type":"articles",
     "id":"1",
     "attributes":{
        "title":"JSON API paints my bikeshed!"
     },
     "relationships":{
        "author":{
           "links":{
              "self":"http://example.com/articles/1/relationships/author",
              "related":"http://example.com/articles/1/author"
           },
           "data":{
              "type":"people",
              "id":"9"
           }
        },
        "comments":{
           "links":{
              "self":"http://example.com/articles/1/relationships/comments",
              "related":"http://example.com/articles/1/comments"
           },
           "data":[
              {
                 "type":"comments",
                 "id":"5"
              },
              {
                 "type":"comments",
                 "id":"12"
              }
           ]
        }
     },
     "links":{
        "self":"http://example.com/articles/1"
     }
  }]}
```

What I am doing is creating Schema class and mentioning every field in it, instead of doing this manual work I want to generate it based on my database model.

So I have used `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` for it and mentioned model name in it, but it returns simple JSON. I want same JSON structure like JSONAPI by using  `marshmallow-sqlalchemy`.

How can I do this?